# How to catch or rescue called process' crash error by calling process in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

I have been trying to figure out how I can catch or rescue in the calling process B an error in another process A that also killed process A.

Here's my code:

```
defmodule A do
  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: :A)
  end

  def fun(fun_loving_person) do
    GenServer.call(fun_loving_person, :have_fun)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    {:ok, %{}}
  end

  def handle_call(:have_fun, _from, state) do
    raise "TooMuchFun"
    {:reply, :ok, state}
  end
end

defmodule B do
  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: :B)
  end

  def spread_fun(fun_seeker) do
    GenServer.call(:B, {:spread_fun, fun_seeker})
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    {:ok, %{}}
  end

  def handle_call({:spread_fun, fun_seeker}, _from, state) do
    result = A.fun(fun_seeker)
    {:reply, result, state}
  rescue
    RuntimeError -> IO.puts "Too much fun rescued"
    {:reply, :error, state}
  end
end

{:ok, a} = A.start_link
{:ok, _b} = B.start_link
result = B.spread_fun(a)
IO.puts "#{inspect result}"
```

In module B's `handle_call` function, I called module A's function and it has `rescue` block in case anything goes wrong with process `:A`. The error is raised but the `rescue` block doesn't get executed.

Have I missed basic understanding of how one process crash affects the other? Does try/catch or try/rescue work only if the error occurs in the same process? Do I have to monitor the other process and trap its exit?

I'll appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish what you like by having another process monitor this process.  Check out `Process.monitor`'s docs: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#monitor/1.

Essentially, the monitoring process will need to handle info for the down message that will be generated upon crashing:

```
handle_info({:DOWN, ref, :process, object, reason}, state) do
  # do something interesting here ...
end
```

Keep in mind you will want to figure out what the `reason`(s) are you want to do this action and pattern match to only include those.

Comment: Thank you. I [modified my example code](https://gist.github.com/ahmadferdous/a5949e47b604dfda564b10c9461985df). B monitors A and implements `handle_info` for :DOWN message. However, B doesn't receive :DOWN message. I'm still looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

In Erlang ecosystem you can catch errors, exits and throws using try-catch only if exception is raised in process's code, but if a process exits with any reason except atom `normal`, all linked process will receive exit signal, those processe which traped exit, will receive this signal as normal erlang message in form of `{'EXIT', CrashedProcessPid, ReasonOfCrash}`. And the other process which did not trap exit, will crash with reason `ReasonOfCrash` and other processes which are linked to these processes will receive signalz and so on.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand you, throwing/raising error and catching/rescuing it must occur in the same process?